# Swift: UIPickerView and text misalignment and iOS 14

Tags: uipickerview

I changed nothing in my code but since I use Xcode 12 my UIPickerview has a strange text alignment when scrolling. Is that a bug in Xcode 12?

[image]

Comment: Maybe the text misalignment happens because I currently use Big Sur beta 8 and Xcode 12?

Comment: I asked Apple about this and here is the answer: "I had further conversations about the issue of the text shifting when it is in the selected area of the picker, and it is recognized as a bug. However, there is no workaround that we can offer."